# GLSL math conditional AND

Tags: debugging, graphics, glsl, vulkan

Maybe I'm not understanding the language or maybe the compiler is doing some kind of black magic but this code is not identical if I uncomment the comment which surprises me because to accept the conditional that should be the value of the variable :

`

```
while (distance < tMax) {
        coords = uvec3(-1, -1, -1);
        
        int active_voxel = volume_data_box_get_coords_from_point(
            mi.block, first_prim_offset, mi.min.xyz, mi.max.xyz,
            mi.slices_by_dimension, mi.memory_size, mi.voxel_size, hit, coords);

        if ((active_voxel == 1) && (coords.x == 0) && (coords.y == 0) &&
            (coords.z == 0)) {          
          // coords.x = 0;
          // coords.y = 0;
          // coords.z = 0;
          bool are_extents = volume_data_box_get_extents_from_coords(
              mi.block, first_prim_offset, mi.min.xyz, mi.slices_by_dimension, mi.memory_size,
              mi.voxel_size, coords, voxel_extents);

          if (are_extents) {
            s = intersectRayOBB(ray.origin, ray.direction, mi.transform,
                                voxel_extents.min, voxel_extents.max);
            tHit = s.t;
            voxel_uv = s.uv;
            hitKind = 1;
            break;
          }
        }
        // Update hit point from previous point plus direction multiplied by
        // voxel size
        hit += ray.direction * mi.voxel_size;
        // Calculate distance between new hit point and ray origin
        distance = length(hit - ray.origin);
      }
```

`

I hope someone can clarify what is going on. Thanks!

The evaluated value is different from the expected one.

Comment: I'm struggling to see how it can be anything other than a compiler error. Do you have any way to test on a different compiler (ideally an updated one if yours is old) or test compiling with less aggressive optimisation settings?

Comment: You were right. It is a compiler optimization and it seems like if the first condition is true the second one is avoided, just obliterated. Thanks!